# crawl website with requests and problem is Object.setPrototypeOf

Tags: python, python-requests, get, web-crawler

i'm trying to crawl website with python requests GET
and having problem with Object.setPrototypeOf
i added userAgent in header but it still gives me under code
i think the problem is Object.setPrototypeOf part. is it corrent?
i need a solution

```
var isSupportedBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') === -1 && typeof Object.setPrototypeOf !== 'undefined';
  if (!isSupportedBrowser) {
    location.replace('/not-supported-browser');
  }
```

i'm trying not to use selenium

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's JavaScript code. To run that code, you need a JavaScript engine. Whether you use one included in a browser or write one yourself is up to you. requests does not include a JavaScript engine.